# Is it possible to disable non-root user's access to certain websites on linux/ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firewall

I am allowing **bad actors** to access my computer via VNC and I would like to to block *access* (mostly browser) to `www.google.com/partners` but not `www.google.com` on my linux computer.

1. I have been browsing around and it doesn't seem like this is feasible via /etc/hosts.
2. I have also looked at IPTables but this wouldn't work as google.com has many ips
3. I am able to achieve this via a chrome plugin but the chrome plugin can easily be disabled by the user.

Are there tools out there, such as firewalls, which can allow me to achieve my goal?

Comment: Firewalls block ports, not URLs

Comment: Use iptables to [block network access to specific users](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189496/how-to-disable-network-access-for-a-user#189499), and set up a proxy (squid, for instance) and tell the users to use the proxy.

Comment: @xenoid wouldn't work. iptables block IPs

Comment: @Sparrowcide *for specific users*. Of course the userid running the proxy process would not be included...

Comment: @xenoid Oh ok so the blocking is really just done by squid. Gotcha. That's a pretty smart approach!

Comment: @xenoid Actually, I don't think this is possible as HTTPS url paths are not blockable without blocking the whole domain (see https://serverfault.com/questions/675593/allow-a-certain-url-path-with-squid).

Comment: Possibly requires a more complete proxy such as BlueCoat (but it's a proprietary solution).